# 32bit device only crash on iOS

Tags: ios, c, core-audio, 32-bit

I'm receiving crash logs for a bug that I cannot reproduce.  The crash only happens on 32bit devices (iPad 4, 3, iPad Mini) so I believe that is a major part of the issue.

The crash occurs on the audio thread, while calculating coefficients for a filter.  The filter is composed of a C struct and related functions... once I had an issue with needing to align structs correctly for 32-bit devices, but I'm not sure that's the case here (and I'm not sure how I would test that!)

Beyond that, I'm stumped. Here are the first couple lines of the function in which it crashes.  The cos function is the second to last frame of the crash log.

```
   void _calculateWithoutUpdatingSetup(ONCBiquadFilter * filter) {
        if (filter->res < 0.01) filter->res = 0.01;
        filter->omega = 2 * M_PI * filter->freq / sampleRate;
        filter->omegaS = sin(filter->omega);
        filter->omegaC = cos(filter->omega);
        filter->alpha = filter->omegaS / (2 * filter->res);

        ///... do a bunch of maths to calculate filter settings
    }
```

And here's the crash log :

```
18
Crashed: AURemoteIO::IOThread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000000
Crashed: AURemoteIO::IOThread
0  myFramework                         0x41077a _calculateWithoutUpdatingSetup + 2417
1  libsystem_m.dylib              0x20b229d8 cos + 584
2  myFramework                         0x40fa2f ONCBiquadFilterCalculateCoefficients + 14
3  myFramework                         0x40fd03 ONCBiquadFilterSetFrequencyAndResonance + 214
4  myFramework                         0x414c7b ONCAterotVoiceSetFilterCutoffAndResonance + 206
5  myFramework                         0x407677 ONCAterotPolyVoicePlay + 452
6  myFramework                         0x3e0d61 ONCAterotLoopStructTick + 1092
7  myApp                     0x21333 DSPRenderCallback (ONCAterotAudioController+AudioRenderCallbacks.m:367)
8  myApp                     0x20b0f renderCallback (ONCAterotAudioController+AudioRenderCallbacks.m:73)
9  AudioToolbox                   0x233224b3 AUInputElement::PullInput(unsigned long&, AudioTimeStamp const&, unsigned long, unsigned long) + 126
10 AudioToolbox                   0x234379ab AUMatrixMixer::Render(unsigned long&, AudioTimeStamp const&, unsigned long) + 554
11 AudioToolbox                   0x234385a5 AUMatrixMixer::RenderBus(unsigned long&, AudioTimeStamp const&, unsigned long, unsigned long) + 104
12 AudioToolbox                   0x23227d01 AUBase::DoRenderBus(unsigned long&, AudioTimeStamp const&, unsigned long, AUOutputElement*, unsigned long, AudioBufferList&) + 148
13 AudioToolbox                   0x23227b91 AUBase::DoRender(unsigned long&, AudioTimeStamp const&, unsigned long, unsigned long, AudioBufferList&) + 740
14 AudioToolbox                   0x232278a3 AUMethodRender(void*, unsigned long*, AudioTimeStamp const*, unsigned long, unsigned long, AudioBufferList*) + 46
15 myApp                     0x65d29 eqCallBack (ONCAterotAudioController+effectCallbacks.m:110)
16 AudioToolbox                   0x233224b3 AUInputElement::PullInput(unsigned long&, AudioTimeStamp const&, unsigned long, unsigned long) + 126
17 AudioToolbox                   0x233f21b1 AUDynamicsProcessor::Render(unsigned long&, AudioTimeStamp const&, unsigned long) + 308
18 AudioToolbox                   0x23227d01 AUBase::DoRenderBus(unsigned long&, AudioTimeStamp const&, unsigned long, AUOutputElement*, unsigned long, AudioBufferList&) + 148
19 AudioToolbox                   0x23227b91 AUBase::DoRender(unsigned long&, AudioTimeStamp const&, unsigned long, unsigned long, AudioBufferList&) + 740
20 AudioToolbox                   0x232278a3 AUMethodRender(void*, unsigned long*, AudioTimeStamp const*, unsigned long, unsigned long, AudioBufferList*) + 46
21 AudioToolbox                   0x23318d89 AUConverterBase::RenderBus(unsigned long&, AudioTimeStamp const&, unsigned long, unsigned long) + 396
22 AudioToolbox                   0x23227d01 AUBase::DoRenderBus(unsigned long&, AudioTimeStamp const&, unsigned long, AUOutputElement*, unsigned long, AudioBufferList&) + 148
23 AudioToolbox                   0x23227b91 AUBase::DoRender(unsigned long&, AudioTimeStamp const&, unsigned long, unsigned long, AudioBufferList&) + 740
24 AudioToolbox                   0x2330864b AURemoteIO::PerformIO(unsigned long, unsigned int, unsigned int, AudioTimeStamp const&, AudioTimeStamp const&, AudioBufferList const*, AudioBufferList*, int&) + 506
25 AudioToolbox                   0x23309851 AURIOCallbackReceiver_PerformIO + 596
26 AudioToolbox                   0x232ff67b _XPerformIO + 166
27 AudioToolbox                   0x23245d69 mshMIGPerform + 184
28 AudioToolbox                   0x232d6533 MSHMIGDispatchMessage + 34
29 AudioToolbox                   0x23308973 AURemoteIO::IOThread::Run() + 118
30 AudioToolbox                   0x2330c331 AURemoteIO::IOThread::Entry(void*) + 8
31 AudioToolbox                   0x232238db CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 186
32 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x20bbcc7f _pthread_body + 138
33 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x20bbcbf3 _pthread_start + 110
34 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x20bbaa08 thread_start + 8
```

Thanks for any guidance in solving this!

Update : I did notice a couple of mistakes on my part -- freq, res, and sampleRate are all floats, while the rest of the values are doubles.  I could see this maybe being part of the issue, though I sort of doubt it as they should just be getting promoted into doubles.

Comment: Check to make sure the pointer \*filter is not nil.  e.g. if (filter != NULL) { /\* the rest of  your function */ };

Comment: If you build on a 64bit system which you probably do, and CoreAudio is `Float32` native, please check if the values which may map into audio data also are of the corresponding data format. How about declaring all the audio data as `Float32` and using `sinf()` and `cosf()` instead?